# How can I make things I copy in my browser added to my Vim registers?

Tags: vim

I want to be able to copy things in my browser and have the available in my Vim register so I can paste them at will. Currently, to paste something from my browser I need to right click on my Vim window and select the 'paste' option. This usually messes up the textual alignment and kind of defeats the whole purpose of using Vim. How can I make things I copy in my browser added to my Vim registers?

Comment: Depends on your environment.  Try `:help clipboard`, but I find `!!xsel` (Linux) or `!!pbpaste` (osx) to be most reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `*`and/or `+` registers. From `:help registers`:

```
7. Selection and drop registers "*, "+ and "~ 
Use these registers for storing and retrieving the selected text for the GUI.
See |quotestar| and |quoteplus|.  When the clipboard is not available or not
working, the unnamed register is used instead.  For Unix systems the clipboard
is only available when the |+xterm_clipboard| feature is present.  {not in Vi}

Note that there is only a distinction between "* and "+ for X11 systems.  For
an explanation of the difference, see |x11-selection|.  Under MS-Windows, use
of "* and "+ is actually synonymous and refers to the |gui-clipboard|.
```

If you require pasting during insert mode, then use `:set paste` before pasting and `:set nopaste` after you no longer need to paste any text. This option will disable many auto-formatting features, such that the pasted text appears as you copied it.